# i want display the date picker in angularJs?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to angularjs.  I want to display the calendar as shown below in angularjs with default of today's date.  Date picker should only allow someone to select today or future (in other words, if the date picker is showing the today, the left arrow should be disabled; when a user clicks on the right arrow, the date should be increase and left arrow should be enabled unless the user left arrows back to today.)

```
                          < Thursday July 30 2015 >
```

Comment: something wrong with your img :)

Comment: i don't have permission to send img...that's y i wrote date as like img plrease help me....

Comment: Your "img" is just fine for showing what you want, but your question could still use some help ... what have you tried?

Comment: Cleaned up grammar; OP still needs to provide what they've tried

Comment: removed image word I had mistakenly left behind

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the below link.

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

```
 <h4>Inline</h4>
<div style="display:inline-block; min-height:290px;">
  <datepicker ng-model="dt" min-date="minDate" show-weeks="true" class="well well-sm" custom-class="getDayClass(date, mode)"></datepicker>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below datepicker :-
https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

For angular :-
https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Installing/#angular-wrapper

And use the minDate() function to disable dates before the current date/default date.